# How to make a snapping header that snaps to each side of the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So while working on my FAQ page, I figured I would try and create a stylish header. The problem is now, that I have it, I have no idea how to snap it to the sides of the browser (if that's even plausible).

What I was wondering if either CSS or JavaScript would help with taking this image: (http://files.enjin.com/503205/FAQWelcome.png) and setting it to a 50-75% height (depending on how it looks) and snap it to the web browser so that the smaller the web browser gets, the smaller the image gets so it maintains the same look in any browser.

I was also wondering if it is possible so that a boatload of pure HTML text could follow the same pattern of expanding and collapsing perhaps?

I'm way too new to CSS but I have an intermediate understanding of how to make it work. I want to be able to create a clean, fluid website that's enjoyable to visit.

Edit: I'm using module placement for this one as Enjin won't support the edit of full-website CSS but rather HTML modules.

Comment: Depending on your target devices/browsers, you should be able to implement this entirely in CSS (if I'm understanding you correctly), especially with CSS attributes like background-size: contain and background-size: cover. JavaScript really shouldn't be necessary here except to maybe change class names

Comment: Enjin doesn't allow the full customization of CSS of the website. Rather, to add HTML, CSS, or JavaScript anywhere in the page, an HTML module must be placed with code inside.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/X7NH7/) in this example image is set as body background

```
body {
  background: #f8f8f8 url(http://files.enjin.com/503205/FAQWelcome.png) top center no-repeat;
}
@media all and (max-width:960px) {

  body {
   background: #f8f8f8 url(http://files.enjin.com/503205/FAQWelcome.png) top center no-repeat;
   background-size: auto 300px;
  } 

}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {

  body {
   background: #f8f8f8 url(http://files.enjin.com/503205/FAQWelcome.png) top center no-repeat;
   background-size: auto 200px;
  } 

}
```

To get responsiveness you must use CSS media queries, with media queries you target screen size and by screen size you're setting appropriate CSS properties.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm using a module with this. Enjin doesn't support straight up CSS towards the pages so using certain CSS aspects Enjin doesn't support itself.

Comment: Sorry pal, can't help you then...but, little advice is learn to write your code and leave engines away ;) Start with HTML5 & CSS2.1, CSS3 than move to JS/jQuery and so on...

Comment: Enjin is a website host that supports a wide range of gaming-oriented websites so it makes it easier for the users (not engines). Anyways, thanks for the actual advice. I've been trying to learn code for a while now and have the basic understanding of it but still struggle on writing my own code. HTML isn't too hard at all as CSS but when it comes to writing it by hand, it takes me a while to grab various code and put it together and rewrite it. Won't hurt to learn it in general.